# Getting XPath of a Picture element image URL

Tags: php, xpath

I am writing some code to scrape 4 bits of information from one of my sites, I can get 3 out of the 4 values back but trying to get the image URL is giving me problems.

code:

```
<?php

function parse($html) {
    try {
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($html);
        $xpath = new DomXPath($doc);

        $nodeList = $xpath->query('//*[@class="productListItem "]');

        $res = [];
        foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
            
            $new = new DomDocument;
            $new->appendChild($new->importNode($node, true));
            $N = new DomXPath($new);
                    
            $nodeLink = $N->query("//a[@class='itemImage']")->item(0);              
            $Link = $nodeLink->getAttribute('href');    
            
            $nodeName = $N->query("//span[@class='itemTitle']")->item(0);
            $Name = $nodeName->textContent;     
            
            $nodeImg = $N->query('...')->item(0);
            $Img = $nodeImg->getAttribute('data-srcset');                                                                                                   
            
            $nodePrice = $N->query("//span[@class='pri']")->item(0);
            $Price = $nodePrice->textContent;
            

            $res[] = [
                'productLink' => $Link,
                'productName' => $Name,
                'productImage' => $Img,
                'productPrice' => $Price
            ];
        }
        return $res;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();      
    }
}

?>
```

In the HTML is this markup (for the image):

```
<picture>
<source data-srcset="https://i8.....net/t/jpl/jd_product_list?plu=jd_528882_plc&amp;qlt=92&amp;w=363&amp;h=463&amp;v=1&amp;fmt=auto 1x, https://i8.....net/t/jpl/jd_product_list?plu=jd_528882_plc&amp;qlt=92&amp;w=726&amp;h=926&amp;v=1&amp;fmt=auto 2x" type="image/webp">
<img width="330" data-e2e="product-listing-img" class="thumbnail img-placeholder imageLazy"          
src="/skins/default/public/img/icons/svg/loading.svg"
data-src="https://i8.....net/t/jpl/jd_product_list?plu=jd_528882_plc&amp;qlt=92&amp;w=363&amp;h=463&amp;v=1&amp;fmt=auto"
data-srcset="
https://i8.....net/t/jpl/jd_product_list?plu=jd_528882_plc&amp;qlt=92&amp;w=363&amp;h=463&amp;v=1&amp;fmt=auto 1x,
https://i8.....net/t/jpl/jd_product_list?plu=jd_528882_plc&amp;qlt=92&amp;w=726&amp;h=926&amp;v=1&amp;fmt=auto 2x"
data-fallbacksrc="/skins/desktop/public/img/products/noimage.png"  data-fallbacksrcset="/skins/desktop/public/img/products/noimage.png 1x, /skins/jdgroup-desktop/public/img/products/noimage-lrg.png 2x" 
alt="..."
title="...">
</picture>

<span class="thumbnail overlay-thumbnail">
<picture>
<source data-srcset="https://i8.....net/t/jpl/jd_product_list?plu=jd_528882_bl&amp;qlt=92&amp;w=363&amp;h=463&amp;v=1&amp;fmt=auto 1x, https://i8.....net/t/jpl/jd_product_list?plu=jd_528882_bl&amp;qlt=92&amp;w=726&amp;h=926&amp;v=1&amp;fmt=auto 2x" type="image/webp">
<img class="imageLazy" width="400" 
data-src="https://i8.....net/t/jpl/jd_product_list?plu=jd_528882_bl&amp;qlt=92&amp;w=363&amp;h=463&amp;v=1&amp;fmt=auto" 
data-srcset="https://i8.....net/t/jpl/jd_product_list?plu=jd_528882_bl&amp;qlt=92&amp;w=363&amp;h=463&amp;v=1&amp;fmt=auto 1x, https://i8.....net/t/jpl/jd_product_list?plu=jd_528882_bl&amp;qlt=92&amp;w=726&amp;h=926&amp;v=1&amp;fmt=auto 2x"
alt="..." 
title="..."
data-fallbacksrc="/skins/desktop/public/img/products/noimage.png"  data-fallbacksrcset="/skins/desktop/public/img/products/noimage.png 1x, /skins/jdgroup-desktop/public/img/products/noimage-lrg.png 2x">
</picture>
</span>
```

It is in a picture element, what I have tried is:

```
$nodeLink = $N->query("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/span/a/picture/img")->item(0);                
$Link = $nodeLink->getAttribute('data-srcset');
```

and

```
$nodeLink = $N->query("//span[@class='thumbnail overlay-thumbnail']")->item(0);             
$Link = $nodeLink->getAttribute('data-srcset');
```

and

```
$nodeLink = $N->query("//img[@class='imageLazy']")->item(0);                
$Link = $nodeLink->getAttribute('data-srcset');
```

3 attempts to get the image URL, on everyone is a NULL value, I cannot seem to get the XPath query correct, at a push I could use regex but I know that is not good to use in these instances, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about php, but I would try using a single XPath expression:

```xml
//img[@class='imageLazy']/@data-srcset
```